# Retrieve files in directory based on php session value

Tags: php

I have working code that displays files from a directory and displays them in a table. However, the first 4 chars of the filename are the client code. So if a user is logged I only need to display the users files and no other. I have looked at substr and can retrieve and echo the first 4 chars of the filename. But, because of the array, this echoes 'DEMODEMODEMODEMODEMODEMO' instead of 'DEMO'. What I am not sure of is how to include a $_SESSION['value']; to compare the chars and if they match the logged in user, then display the files.

I have posted the relevant part of the code and would be grateful if someone could give me some help with this. The filename is in the format: DEMO_236592_cert.pdf and the first 4 chars are all i need to retrieve. many thanks

```
<?php

foreach ($fff as $filedata)
{
    // SKIP THE "DOT" FILES
    if ($filedata->isDot()) continue;

    // ACTIVATE THIS LINE TO RESTRICT IT TO PDF FILES ONLY
    if ($filedata->getExtension() != 'pdf') continue;

    // CREATE LINKS TO THESE FILES
    $nom = $filedata->getFilename();
    $result = substr ($nom, 0, 4);
    echo $result;

    $lnk
    = '<img src="destcerts/PDF_icon_100.png" style="margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top:15px;"><br /><a href="'
    . $sub
    . '/'
    . $nom
    . '" style="color:#0099FF; text-decoration:none; font-size:12px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">'
    . $nom
    . '</a>'
    ;

    // COLLECT THE LINKS HERE
    $sss[] = $lnk;
}

?>
```

Comment: you're doing the echo in a loop, so you'll get `DEMO` for every file being iterated. e.g. you have 10 files that start with `DEMO`, you'll get `DEMO` echoed 10 times.

Comment: The loop as you can see is there to load all files in that directory. However, what I am trying to do is, only load the files that belong to the logged in user. Hence the DEMO part in the filename. Hope that is clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($_SESSION['my_var']!==$result){continue;}
```

I assume you have already validated and filtered the session variable beforehand somewhere.

Comment: Thanks very much. Got me started in the right direction.